# An easy way to create a Bas Relief from 3d Model

Tags: modeling

ZBrush has a nifty (easy to use, few steps) way to convert 3d models into Bas Reliefs.  So far my searching for a Blender equivalents point to what appear to be quite fiddly use of heights maps from misty renders.

Is there an equivalent more nifty way to make Bas Reliefs of 3d models in Blender?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way that comes into my mind is to bake the Position of an object onto a plane with the cycles render engine (1 sample is enough).

The blue channel of the resulting images should constitute a good height map to work with. If one is able to properly bake a texture, the whole setup process takes less than a minute.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply.  I'll follow up on your advice when I'm next back at my PC.Cheers